Why are the correlation coefficients not being displayed on this heatmap?
the correlation coefficients are only being displayed over the 'Age' variable.
printing the correlation matrix has normal results.
Here is the python script:
package settings:
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# settings
plt.style.use('seaborn-v0_8')
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)



subset = tbi_data[['Age',
 '6MWT T0',
 '6MWT T0 PA',
 '6MWT T3',
 '6MWT T3 PA',
 '6MWT dLOS',
 '10MWT T0',
 '10MWT T0 PA',
 '10MWT T3',
 '10MWT T3 PA',
 '10MWT dLOS',
 'BBS T0',
 'BBS T3',
 'BBS dLOS',
 'FGA T0',
 'FGA T3']]

corr_matrix = subset.corr()

# heatmap
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
sns.heatmap(corr_matrix, annot=True, cmap='coolwarm', fmt=".2f", cbar=True, annot_kws={"size": 10})
plt.title('Correlation Matrix Heatmap', fontsize=16)  # Adjust title font size

plt.show()

heatmap image
example of some of the data after print(corr_matrix)
              Age   6MWT T0  6MWT T0 PA   6MWT T3  6MWT T3 PA  6MWT dLOS  \

Age          1.000000 -0.141936    0.035992 -0.075920    0.067520  -0.039798
6MWT T0     -0.141936  1.000000    0.676726  0.735785    0.372823  -0.061586
6MWT T0 PA   0.035992  0.676726    1.000000  0.614821    0.365432   0.123143
6MWT T3     -0.075920  0.735785    0.614821  1.000000    0.506620   0.628984
6MWT T3 PA   0.067520  0.372823    0.365432  0.506620    1.000000   0.324495
6MWT dLOS   -0.039798 -0.061586    0.123143  0.628984    0.324495   1.000000
10MWT T0    -0.152968  0.838115    0.538780  0.804867    0.393774   0.219045
10MWT T0 PA  0.052394  0.465580    0.607639  0.522268    0.370320   0.193433
10MWT T3    -0.065719  0.652372    0.594354  0.834630    0.408358   0.522014
10MWT T3 PA -0.062076  0.442841    0.457291  0.558615    0.649488   0.350294
10MWT dLOS  -0.049791  0.022179    0.168327  0.270161    0.114166   0.390974
BBS T0      -0.045725  0.783241    0.662747  0.793061    0.447369   0.258789
BBS T3      -0.056059  0.615279    0.631905  0.815999    0.536779   0.519272
BBS dLOS    -0.097124 -0.121210    0.062953  0.179966    0.223446   0.426376
FGA T0       0.056571  0.736978    0.498391  0.549865    0.339682  -0.049252
FGA T3       0.053177  0.578839    0.504757  0.803587    0.533340   0.515129

Did you try to upgrade seaborn to the latest version?

yes, thank you both! Upgrading seaborn worked- had to use conda forge since the normal conda is still 0.12. and will not work.
